# Why is nearley-unparse not including tokens in sample strings generated from a compiled Nearley grammar when using Moo as tokenizer/lexer

Tags: javascript, parsing, context-free-grammar, lexer, nearley

I'm not sure whether this a problem with the [Nearley.js library](https://nearley.js.org/), the [Moo tokenizer/lexer](https://github.com/no-context/moo) or with my own code. So I might need to submit this as an issue to the Nearley repo. All the referenced files can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/RobRoseKnows/bd07de0059bd0da0b96f1d9253e9a27d).

I am attempting to write a Nearley grammar that will parse a list of homework problems for one of my classes. The problems are in [problems.txt](https://gist.github.com/RobRoseKnows/bd07de0059bd0da0b96f1d9253e9a27d#file-problems-txt) and look like this:

```
Section 5.2 (Due 4/23)- #3, 5*, 8*, 9, 11, 14*, 15, 17*, 18*, 20, 21*, 22*, 24*, 25 (see example 5, not discussed in class)
Section 5.3 (Due 4/30)- #1, 3*, 4, 5, 6*, 7, 9*, 11, 13*, 16, 20*, 21*, 22*, 23, 24*, 25*, 27, 28*, 31, 32
```

That's just two lines as an example, whole file is larger.

The Nearley grammar I wrote is in `problems-grammar.ne` [here](https://gist.github.com/RobRoseKnows/bd07de0059bd0da0b96f1d9253e9a27d#file-problems-grammar-ne) and I'm not entirely finished yet. I'm using the Moo tokenizer/lexer according to [these instructions](https://nearley.js.org/docs/tokenizers) in the Nearley docs.

I'm currently testing my grammar by using the `nearley-unparse` command as explained [here](https://nearley.js.org/docs/tooling#nearley-unparse-the-unparser) using this command, where `problems-grammar.js` is the parser compiled by Nearley.

```
nearley-unparse problems-grammar.js -o test.txt
```

Unfortunately, the unparser doesn't seem to be correctly generating grammars with examples of the tokens, apart from the newline token. [Here](https://gist.github.com/RobRoseKnows/bd07de0059bd0da0b96f1d9253e9a27d#file-test-txt) is one output of `nearley-unparse`:

```
Section  (Due )- #*, , 
Section  (Due )- #, *, 
Section  (Due )- #*, , , *, 
Section  (Due )- #*, *
Section  (Due )- #*, *, *, *
```

I'm wondering whether this is a flaw in my grammar or a flaw with Nearley/Moo itself. If it's a problem with my code, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't receive an answer from here I went ahead and [asked in the Nearley GitHub repo](https://github.com/kach/nearley/issues/341).

According to the maintainers, `nearley-unparse` can't currently generate strings to match a regular expression. There also aren't any plans to add that functionality as it would be a project in and of itself.

Here is their full response:

> Hello there! Thanks for trying to post a StackOverflow question first,
>   I’m sorry there wasn’t anyone able to help there :-)
>
> This is a limitation of the unparser: it doesn’t know how to generate
>   random strings satisfying a regexp, nor are we planning to do so (that
>   would be a project in itself!).
>
> Your grammar looks fine to me, at a brief glance; if you test it with
>   nearley-test, hopefully you’ll find you get the parse trees you
>   expect.